# TempData issue in chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have used TempData in the following manner:

```
Controller:
TempData["Error"]="First error";

View:
var error=TempData["Error"];
@error
```

The above code works perfectly with IE. But in chrome the TempData is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I dont think that you should use `TempData` for this.

For you problem, below is what you should use.

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.Error="First error";
```

**View:**

```
@ViewBag.Error
```

Hope this helps.

**Update** : [See this article](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-pass-values-from-controller-to-view-using-viewbag-in-mvc-3/)
Ideally the above code should work, but you say it doesnt. Can I see how you are calling your view ? and more of your code.

Comment: I have tried using ViewBag but still I am not able to view the error

Answer (score 0):

Tempdata and Viewdata should generally  be avoided as it isn't strongly typed and creeps into code in bad places. Avoid it and use a viewmodel to pass data to your view.

In your controller:

```
var model = new YourViewModel();
model.Error = "your message";
return View(model);
```

However without knowing what you are using it for there may be a better way. Whats the bigger picture here of what you ate trying to design?